# Read all data on Indy Server buffer

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal

I have in TCP/IP a client that send a list of strings with `writeln` (all at the same time).
How can the TCPserver know that it has read all the data?
In `Onexecute` event, I have used:

```
If (not AThread.Terminated)and(athread.Connection.Connected) then
  Memo1.lines.add(AThread.Connection.readln);
```

But the problem, is that some last lines are not read.

Answer (score 1):

You should send each string with its own `WriteLn()`, then you can either:

1. Send the number of strings before sending the actual strings. The server can then read the number first, then call `ReadLn()` however many times the number says.
2. Send a unique terminating line after the strings. The server can then keep calling `ReadLn()` until the terminator is read. If you need to send a string that could be ambiquious with the terminator, escape the string before sending it, and then have the server unescape it  after reading it.

Indy has reading/writing methods for handling both scenarios, such as `WriteStrings()`, `ReadStrings()`, `WriteRFCStrings()`, `Capture()`, etc.

On an unrelated note, you should not be checking the `AThread.Terminated` and `AThread.Connection.Connected` properties. Let Indy raise an exception if you try to read from or write to a disconnected socket, and let the server handle the exception. Also, `TIdTCPServer` is multi-threaded, and accessing UI controls in the `OnExecute` event (or `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, or `OnException`) is not thread-safe. You MUST synchronize with the main UI thread to access them safely.

Comment: Or you can wing it based on timing. If no new data for xxx ms, then terminate.